# What font is used for Pandemobium's logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: Pandemobium's logo]

Can anybody help me figure out what font used in this image? I had tried using myfonts.com as well as whatfontis.com but couldn't get the exact font.

Ubuntu font and FF Dax are close, but not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Identifont](http://www.identifont.com) pulled through for me!

This typeface is [Aller](http://www.daltonmaag.com/buyonline/fonts/aller) by Dalton Maag. It's available there, [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Aller), and in other places as well, I'm sure.

[image: Pandemobium screen capture]

Comment: As well as designing Aller, the correct match, Dalton Maag also designed Ubuntu font, one of the near misses that the asker mentioned.